# combining two shapes into one shape via svg

Tags: svg

im quite new to svg and wanted to know how to create this shape. ive managed to create a simple dotted line. i was thinking if it was possible to create 2 shapes and then position them to make it look like one whole. ORRR can i make this shape just using svg?

```
<svg height="150px" viewBox="0 0 200 300">
                                <line
                                  x1="100" x2="100"
                                  y1="10" y2="300"
                                  stroke="#e6eaed"
                                  stroke-width="10"
                                  stroke-linecap="round"
                                  stroke-dasharray="1, 37" />
                                </svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. You just need to add an additional line for the horizontal section.

```html
<svg width="50" height="200">
  
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="6"
     stroke-linecap="round"
     stroke-dasharray="0 10">
    <line x1="40" y1="10" x2="40" y2="190"/>
    <line x1="10" y1="100" x2="40" y2="100"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a big difference in complexity between rendering two shapes on top of each other and actually combining the shapes.

Rendering ontop of each other is as simple as setting the origin of both shapes to be the same point and then rendering them in some arbitrary order.

Combining the shapes will require you to come up with some rules on how to perform the combination or merge operation. For instance, do you want to simply take all the points that define shape A and append them to the set of points that define shape B? Hint; probably not as you'll then most likely just end up with criss crossing lines (much the same as if you'd just rendered them on top of each other). Instead you'd want to look at doing some sort of intersection to find the resulting area and then defining the resulting shape from the points that define said area (look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons for a start).